# node.js create hidden directory (Windows)

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I create a **hidden directory** using **node.js under Windows**?

On Linux I would use:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.mkdirSync(".hiddenDir");
```

but on Windows I need to additionally set the HIDDEN attribute of the directory.

In Perl I would use:

```
Win32::File::SetAttributes(".hiddenDir", Win32::File::DIRECTORY() | Win32::File::HIDDEN());
```

Comment: not sure this is possible at the moment

Comment: Is there a platform independent way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a library available to handle this, `fswin`:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/fswin

See the documentation for `setAttribute` here:

https://github.com/xxoo/node-fswin/wiki/setAttributes-and-setAttributesSync

In other words:

```
fswin.setAttributesSync('test.txt', { IS_HIDDEN: true });
```

Note that this requires a native compiler (it lists Visual Studio in the documentation, but perhaps others could be used).

Answer (score 7):

You could try executing the [DOS command attrib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATTRIB) using [child_process.spawn()](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

Answer (score 6):

I've used library [hidefile](https://github.com/stevenvachon/hidefile), to **Hide files and directories on all the platforms**.

```
const hidefile = require('hidefile');

hidefile.hideSync('.hiddenDir');
```

No extra code to write for diff platforms.
I've used this on my Electron JS Desktop App. Which works properly for all the platforms.